# OpenCV GpuMat usage

Tags: opencv, cuda, gpu

I'm trying to use OpenCV GpuMat but I'm getting an assert error, my code is as follows

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp"

// ...

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::gpu;

int main()
{
    string baboon = "baboon.jpg";
    try
    {
        DeviceInfo info = getDevice();
        cout << info.name() << endl;

        GpuMat src;

        src = cv::imread(baboon, 1);
    }
    catch (const cv::Exception* ex)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << ex->what() << endl;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
GeForce GTX 550 Ti
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!m.empty()) in unknown function, file ($PATH_TO_OPENCV)\opencv\modules\gpu\src\gpumat.cpp, line 411
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is:

```
Mat src;

src = cv::imread("...");

GpuMat dst;

dst.upload(src);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it just be dst.upload(src); ?

Answer (score 4):

I believe it throws the assert in the `GpuMat` constructor because your call to `imread` returns null, and hence your Gpu Matrix is empty / not defined.

This means that your image can not be read probably due because of missing file, improper permissions or an unsupported or invalid format.

Verify that *baboon.jpg* exists in the same directory as where you are running your program, also verify that your image file has the correct permissions and isn't corrupt.